# Black screen before grub after nvidia driver update

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

Yesterday I updated the NVIDIA driver on my computer to the 535 version (the old driver is the open source xorg). My graphic card is Geforce MX150. That was probably a wrong driver install. But then I restarted the computer. When it reboots, there is no grub screen, no blinking cursor, nothing. Just a dim light on a black screen. I am having no way to poke into the OS or package system right now.

I tried many things I saw on the internet (press Right Shift, CTRL ALT F1-F7, etc.) but almost nothing works. The only thing that “works” is CTRL ALT DEL, which reboots the computer again.

Please help me revive the computer. Thanks a ton.